# How would I get a cron job to run per 30 minutes?

Tags: cron

I put below into crontab,but it not working.

```
*/30 7-20 * * * pgrep -f crawl_index.py > /dev/null || python3.6 /htdocs/crawl/crawl_index.py >> /var/log/py-crawl.log 2>&1
*/10 7-20 * * * pgrep -f download_url.py > /dev/null || python3.6 /htdocs/crawl/download_url.py >> /var/log/py-download.log 2>&1
```

but when I run `pgrep -f download_url.py > /dev/null || python3.6 /htdocs/crawl/download_url.py >> /var/log/py-download.log 2>&1` it works

Comment: Try to provide the full path to the programs you are trying to run. Automatically resolving paths like on the command line doesn't always work with cron. Also make sure that the user you've set the cron up with has the required permissions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Most of the cron executables will execute a script every 30 minutes with:

```
*/30 * * * * (command to be executed)
```

For older cron executables that don't understand the */x notation, the script can be run every 30 minutes by adding the below line in your crontab:

```
0,30 * * * * (command to be executed)
```

This command runs at the 0th and 30th minute of every hour, so basically every 30 minutes. The minutes 0 and 30 may be changed based on your requirement to 1 and 31 or 2 and 32 etc, still running every 30 minutes.

See [this link](http://crontab.org/) for the documentation

Comment: This adds nothing valuable. */30 works fine just like OP has it now.